# What's an efficient (or the most efficient) way to index nested lists/environments?

Tags: list, r, indexing, nested

I love the flexibility of lists in contexts where objects of formal classes are too inflexible. Basically, they could be used to map the way of handling tree structures that we are conceptually used to from our OS's standard file system.

Yet, in order to master "degrees of nestedness" exceeding 3 or 4, you need a way of computing an index of your nested list. Once you have such an index, it's not really difficult to select a specific branch, update it, add new branches to the list, in short: doing all the stuff we'd also do with files and folders in our OS's file system.

### Example

Basically, `str(object)` gets the job done already, but only outputs text (`capture.output(str(object))`. I'm after transforming that into a data frame structure

**Example list**

```
setClass("TESTCLASS_X", representation=representation(a="numeric"))
setRefClass("TESTCLASS_Y", fields=list(a="numeric"))

src <- list(
    a=list(
        a.1=list(a.1.1 = 1, a.1.2 = 1:5, a.1.3 = integer(0)),
        a.2=list(a.2.1="a", a.2.2=c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"), a.2.3=character()),
        a.3=list(a.3.1=1.5, a.3.2=c(1.5, 2.5), a.3.3=numeric()), 
        a.4=list(a.4.1=1+1i, a.4.2=c(0.1+0.3i, 0.2+0.2i, 0.1+0.1i), a.4.3=complex()),  
        a.5=list(a.5.1 = TRUE, a.5.2 = c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE), a.5.3 = logical())
    ), 
    b=list(
        b.1=list(
            b.1.1=list(b.1.1.1 =matrix(1, ncol=1),
                b.1.1.2=matrix(c(1:4), ncol=2, dimnames=list(NULL, c("a","b"))),
                b.1.1.3=matrix()
            ),
            b.1.2=list(b.1.2.1=data.frame(1), b.1.2.2=data.frame(a=1:3, b=1:3),
                b.1.2.3=data.frame() 
            )
        ),
        b.2=list(
            b.2.1=list(b.2.1.1=list(a=1), b.2.1.2=list(a=1:2, b=letters[1:2]),
                b.2.1.3=list(a=1:2, b="a", c=1:3, d=FALSE, e=1:5), b.2.1.4=list()
            )
        )
    ),
    c=list(
        c.1=list(c.1.1=new.env(), c.1.2=new("TESTCLASS_X", a=1:5), 
            c.1.3=new("TESTCLASS_Y", a=1:5))
    )
)
```

**Desired output**

```
                    name pos is.top is.bottom       class is.s4  dim
1                      a   1   TRUE     FALSE        list FALSE    5
2                  a/a.1   2  FALSE     FALSE        list FALSE    3
3            a/a.1/a.1.1   3  FALSE      TRUE     numeric FALSE    1
4            a/a.1/a.1.2   3  FALSE      TRUE     integer FALSE    5
5            a/a.1/a.1.3   3  FALSE      TRUE     integer FALSE    0
6                  a/a.2   2  FALSE     FALSE        list FALSE    3
7            a/a.2/a.2.1   3  FALSE      TRUE   character FALSE    1
8            a/a.2/a.2.2   3  FALSE      TRUE   character FALSE    5
9            a/a.2/a.2.3   3  FALSE      TRUE   character FALSE    0
10                 a/a.3   2  FALSE     FALSE        list FALSE    3
11           a/a.3/a.3.1   3  FALSE      TRUE     numeric FALSE    1
12           a/a.3/a.3.2   3  FALSE      TRUE     numeric FALSE    2
13           a/a.3/a.3.3   3  FALSE      TRUE     numeric FALSE    0
14                 a/a.4   2  FALSE     FALSE        list FALSE    3
15           a/a.4/a.4.1   3  FALSE      TRUE     complex FALSE    1
16           a/a.4/a.4.2   3  FALSE      TRUE     complex FALSE    3
17           a/a.4/a.4.3   3  FALSE      TRUE     complex FALSE    0
18                 a/a.5   2  FALSE     FALSE        list FALSE    3
19           a/a.5/a.5.1   3  FALSE      TRUE     logical FALSE    1
20           a/a.5/a.5.2   3  FALSE      TRUE     logical FALSE    3
21           a/a.5/a.5.3   3  FALSE      TRUE     logical FALSE    0
22                     b   1   TRUE     FALSE        list FALSE    2
23                 b/b.1   2  FALSE     FALSE        list FALSE    2
24           b/b.1/b.1.1   3  FALSE     FALSE        list FALSE    3
25   b/b.1/b.1.1/b.1.1.1   4  FALSE      TRUE      matrix FALSE  1-1
26   b/b.1/b.1.1/b.1.1.2   4  FALSE      TRUE      matrix FALSE  2-2
27   b/b.1/b.1.1/b.1.1.3   4  FALSE      TRUE      matrix FALSE  1-1
28           b/b.1/b.1.2   3  FALSE     FALSE        list FALSE    3
29   b/b.1/b.1.2/b.1.2.1   4  FALSE      TRUE  data.frame FALSE  1-1
30   b/b.1/b.1.2/b.1.2.2   4  FALSE      TRUE  data.frame FALSE  3-2
31   b/b.1/b.1.2/b.1.2.3   4  FALSE      TRUE  data.frame FALSE  0-0
32                 b/b.2   2  FALSE     FALSE        list FALSE    1
33           b/b.2/b.2.1   3  FALSE     FALSE        list FALSE    4
34   b/b.2/b.2.1/b.2.1.1   4  FALSE     FALSE        list FALSE    1
35 b/b.2/b.2.1/b.2.1.1/a   5  FALSE      TRUE     numeric FALSE    1
36   b/b.2/b.2.1/b.2.1.2   4  FALSE     FALSE        list FALSE    2
37 b/b.2/b.2.1/b.2.1.2/a   5  FALSE      TRUE     integer FALSE    2
38 b/b.2/b.2.1/b.2.1.2/b   5  FALSE      TRUE   character FALSE    2
39   b/b.2/b.2.1/b.2.1.3   4  FALSE     FALSE        list FALSE    5
40 b/b.2/b.2.1/b.2.1.3/a   5  FALSE      TRUE     integer FALSE    2
41 b/b.2/b.2.1/b.2.1.3/b   5  FALSE      TRUE   character FALSE    1
42 b/b.2/b.2.1/b.2.1.3/c   5  FALSE      TRUE     integer FALSE    3
43 b/b.2/b.2.1/b.2.1.3/d   5  FALSE      TRUE     logical FALSE    1
44 b/b.2/b.2.1/b.2.1.3/e   5  FALSE      TRUE     integer FALSE    5
45   b/b.2/b.2.1/b.2.1.4   4  FALSE     FALSE        list FALSE    0
46                     c   1   TRUE     FALSE        list FALSE    1
47                 c/c.1   2  FALSE     FALSE        list FALSE    3
48           c/c.1/c.1.1   3  FALSE      TRUE environment FALSE <NA>
49           c/c.1/c.1.2   3  FALSE      TRUE TESTCLASS_X  TRUE    1
50           c/c.1/c.1.3   3  FALSE      TRUE TESTCLASS_Y  TRUE    1
```

### EDIT 2011-11-21

Spacedman asked me if that isn't simply the result of a depth-first search. Well, it definitely is, but

1. I struggled with the recursive nature of it
2. I thought that a "manual" depth-first will probably always be less efficient than relying on `capture.output(str()` since that is based on C (IIRC)

Here's something similar to my first depth-first approaches:

`src` is taken from above

```
objIndex <- function(src){
    out <- lapply(1:length(src), function(x){
        if(class(src[[x]]) == "list"){
            if(length(src[[x]])){
                df.1 <- objIndex(src=src[[x]])
            } else {
                df.1 <- data.frame(
                    path=names(src[x]),
                    pos=NA,
                    is.top=FALSE,
                    is.bottom=TRUE,
                    class=class(src[[x]]),
                    dim=length(src[[x]])
                )    
            }
        } else {
            df.1 <- data.frame(
                path=ifelse(is.null(names(src[x])), NA, names(src[x])),
                pos=NA,
                is.top=FALSE,
                is.bottom=TRUE,
                class=class(src[[x]]),
                dim=length(src[[x]])
            )    
        }  
        df.1
    })
    return(out)
}
> objIndex(src, df=NULL)
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[[1]][[1]][[1]]
   path pos is.top is.bottom   class dim
1 a.1.1  NA  FALSE      TRUE numeric   1

[[1]][[1]][[2]]
   path pos is.top is.bottom   class dim
1 a.1.2  NA  FALSE      TRUE integer   5

[[1]][[1]][[3]]
   path pos is.top is.bottom   class dim
1 a.1.3  NA  FALSE      TRUE integer   0


[[1]][[2]]
[[1]][[2]][[1]]
   path pos is.top is.bottom     class dim
1 a.2.1  NA  FALSE      TRUE character   1

[[1]][[2]][[2]]
   path pos is.top is.bottom     class dim
1 a.2.2  NA  FALSE      TRUE character   5

[[1]][[2]][[3]]
   path pos is.top is.bottom     class dim
1 a.2.3  NA  FALSE      TRUE character   0


[[1]][[3]]
[[1]][[3]][[1]]
   path pos is.top is.bottom   class dim
1 a.3.1  NA  FALSE      TRUE numeric   1

[[1]][[3]][[2]]
   path pos is.top is.bottom   class dim
1 a.3.2  NA  FALSE      TRUE numeric   2

[[1]][[3]][[3]]
   path pos is.top is.bottom   class dim
1 a.3.3  NA  FALSE      TRUE numeric   0


[[1]][[4]]
[[1]][[4]][[1]]
   path pos is.top is.bottom   class dim
1 a.4.1  NA  FALSE      TRUE complex   1

[[1]][[4]][[2]]
   path pos is.top is.bottom   class dim
1 a.4.2  NA  FALSE      TRUE complex   3

[[1]][[4]][[3]]
   path pos is.top is.bottom   class dim
1 a.4.3  NA  FALSE      TRUE complex   0


[[1]][[5]]
[[1]][[5]][[1]]
   path pos is.top is.bottom   class dim
1 a.5.1  NA  FALSE      TRUE logical   1

[[1]][[5]][[2]]
   path pos is.top is.bottom   class dim
1 a.5.2  NA  FALSE      TRUE logical   3

[[1]][[5]][[3]]
   path pos is.top is.bottom   class dim
1 a.5.3  NA  FALSE      TRUE logical   0



[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[[2]][[1]][[1]]
[[2]][[1]][[1]][[1]]
     path pos is.top is.bottom  class dim
1 b.1.1.1  NA  FALSE      TRUE matrix   1

[[2]][[1]][[1]][[2]]
     path pos is.top is.bottom  class dim
1 b.1.1.2  NA  FALSE      TRUE matrix   4

[[2]][[1]][[1]][[3]]
     path pos is.top is.bottom  class dim
1 b.1.1.3  NA  FALSE      TRUE matrix   1


[[2]][[1]][[2]]
[[2]][[1]][[2]][[1]]
     path pos is.top is.bottom      class dim
1 b.1.2.1  NA  FALSE      TRUE data.frame   1

[[2]][[1]][[2]][[2]]
     path pos is.top is.bottom      class dim
1 b.1.2.2  NA  FALSE      TRUE data.frame   2

[[2]][[1]][[2]][[3]]
     path pos is.top is.bottom      class dim
1 b.1.2.3  NA  FALSE      TRUE data.frame   0



[[2]][[2]]
[[2]][[2]][[1]]
[[2]][[2]][[1]][[1]]
[[2]][[2]][[1]][[1]][[1]]
   path pos is.top is.bottom   class dim
1 <<1>>  NA  FALSE      TRUE numeric   1


[[2]][[2]][[1]][[2]]
[[2]][[2]][[1]][[2]][[1]]
  path pos is.top is.bottom   class dim
1    a  NA  FALSE      TRUE integer   2

[[2]][[2]][[1]][[2]][[2]]
  path pos is.top is.bottom     class dim
1    b  NA  FALSE      TRUE character   2


[[2]][[2]][[1]][[3]]
[[2]][[2]][[1]][[3]][[1]]
   path pos is.top is.bottom   class dim
1 <<1>>  NA  FALSE      TRUE integer   2

[[2]][[2]][[1]][[3]][[2]]
   path pos is.top is.bottom     class dim
1 <<2>>  NA  FALSE      TRUE character   1

[[2]][[2]][[1]][[3]][[3]]
   path pos is.top is.bottom   class dim
1 <<3>>  NA  FALSE      TRUE integer   3

[[2]][[2]][[1]][[3]][[4]]
   path pos is.top is.bottom   class dim
1 <<4>>  NA  FALSE      TRUE logical   1

[[2]][[2]][[1]][[3]][[5]]
   path pos is.top is.bottom   class dim
1 <<5>>  NA  FALSE      TRUE integer   5


[[2]][[2]][[1]][[4]]
     path pos is.top is.bottom class dim
1 b.2.1.4  NA  FALSE      TRUE  list   0




[[3]]
[[3]][[1]]
[[3]][[1]][[1]]
   path pos is.top is.bottom       class dim
1 c.1.1  NA  FALSE      TRUE environment   0

[[3]][[1]][[2]]
   path pos is.top is.bottom       class dim
1 c.1.2  NA  FALSE      TRUE TESTCLASS_X   1

[[3]][[1]][[3]]
   path pos is.top is.bottom       class dim
1 c.1.3  NA  FALSE      TRUE TESTCLASS_Y   1
```

Comment: Is this just the output of a depth-first search?

Comment: Yes and no: depth-first was my first approach, but I went mad with the recursiveness ;-). Function `str()` is killer with respect to solving this much more efficiently, but only outputs text (`capture.output(str())`, that is). So I went ahead with all sorts of regex stuff (for details, see my answer below). I proposed updating `unlist()` to `unlist(do.names=TRUE, delim.names="/")` once but didn't raise any interest. Maybe I'll try promoting updating `str()` to `str(output="data.frame")` to have it output an df like the one above.

Comment: I still dont see how your output is not the result of a depth-first search - start at a, then down to a.1, down to a.1.1 - cant go any deeper so do a.1.2 and a.1.3 - thats that level done, so up to a.2. It looks like the sequence from a classic depth-first search.

Comment: That's true and I've let this issue sit for quite a while. IIRC, there where a couple of issues with a "simple" depth-first search, if only with respect to efficiency. But I'll check this again.

Comment: @Spacedman: would you mind showing me how would do that based from my approach (see edit above) - if you got the time? I can't really grasp how to resolve the nestedness and how to end up with a nice df in the end. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: There's a depth-first search function, `dfs`, in `RBGL` but it only work on objects of class `graph`. http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/2.9/bioc/html/RBGL.html

Comment: Just a thought: you are determining 'bottom' by the absence of names.  However, a list element is not required to have a name, viz: `foo<-list(2,4,5) ; names(foo) #NULL `

Comment: @CarlWitthoft: that's true, but I have a little function taking care of that: list(2,4,5) would turn into list("<<1>>"=2, "<<2>>"=4, "<<3>>"=5). Clearly some workaround, but as I'm primarily planning on using this stuff for mapping configs, there should be no missing names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A partial solution can be obtained with `rapply`. This only calculates values for the end nodes, so you get the portion of the data frame where `is.bottom` is `TRUE`.  Getting the rest of the table should be possible from inspecting names, but I suspect its faffy, and those nodes are fairly boring (all just `class = "list"`, `is.S4 = FALSE`).

The `class` and `is.S4` columns are easy to obtain.

```
out_class <- rapply(src, class)    
out_isS4 <- rapply(src, isS4)
```

I'm not quite sure what you are doing with the `dim` column, but a similar call should get you started.

```
out_dim <- rapply(src, length)
```

Do get the names how you want them, we use the trick that you want the slash separators where there is a dot followed by a letter.  This will probably break if you don't have named elements in the list, though I've not tested it.

```
sep <- "/"
out_name <- gsub("\\.(?=[[:alpha:]])", sep, names(out_class), perl = TRUE)
```

Likewise, the depth of nesting can be found from the number of slashes that you just added to the names.

```
out_pos <- sapply(strsplit(out_name, sep), length)
```

Finally, we combine these into a data frame.

```
(out <- data.frame(
  name = out_name,
  pos = out_pos,
  class = out_class,
  is.S4 = out_isS4,
  dim = out_dim  
))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! +1 for the pointer to rapply and a really fast solution (0.003505048 using `microbenchmark`; mine had something like 0.33)! Two comments/questions: I've struggled with retrieving the "path names" as well. Unfortunately, everything from `unlist()` to the various flavors of `apply()` won't let you choose how names should be separated. So I guess it's either "take it (= ensure letter + something) or leave it" in that respect, right? Second, I don't really see how I would take the resulting object and easily compute the "parent layers" from it. Any suggestions?

Comment: Regarding your question about the `dim` column: I've tried to copy what `str()` gives me. That way you can easily search for branches with `class = "something"` and `dim = xyz`.

Comment: Yes, names must begin with a letter with this solution.  You should be able to achieve that via `names(x) <- make.names(x)`.  Possibly with `unique = TRUE`.

Comment: I've just had a play with computing parent layers and it's awful.  My plan was to mess about with `strsplit(out_name, sep)` and various combinations of `length`, `table` and the `*apply` functions.  Mostly I ended up in crazy recursion hell.  After this experience, I think you are probably better off if you can do without this part of the data frame, since it will likely be very messy getting a solution.  (Looking forward to being proved wrong.)

Comment: I was just curious with the `dim` column because clearly `3-2` isn't numeric, which is the type you might expect the column to be.

Comment: Thanks for trying the parent part. That's where I ended up as well: recursion hell ;-) I did come up with a solution that produced the df above, just have a look at my answer/blog if you're interested (again: sorry for the formatting, but it's Wordpress's fault).

Comment: Regarding `dim`: I wanted to bring `dim()` and `length()` info together in own column. My routines take into account that it's character and coerce it accordingly (strsplitting dims).

Answer (score 0):

After two crappy approaches, I came up with the one posted [here](http://rappster.wordpress.com/2011/11/20/indexing-nested-lists/). Yet it still feels like this is too complicated and that it could be realized easier.

I'm very sorry for the messed up format! I'll move the code to a Github repo in a couple of days.